# JSR-303 bean validation - avoid bypassing a field

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, bean-validation

Suppose we have this bean

```
public class Bean {
   @NotBlank(groups = {CheckForEmployee.class, CheckForAdmins.class})
   private String sth1;

   @NotBlank(groups = {CheckForAdmins.class})
   private String sth2;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Now in the Employee UI we have something like this:

```
<input name="sth1" type="text" />
```

and this is for admin:

```
<input name="sth1" type="text" />
<input name="sth2" type="text" />
```

We all know frameworks like Spring can bind these values to the Bean object, for example in Spring we have something like this:

```
public ModelAndView method1 (@Validated({CheckForEmployee.class})@ModelAttribute Bean bean){...} 
//For Employee
AND
public ModelAndView method2 (@Validated({CheckForAdmin.class})@ModelAttribute Bean bean){...} 
//For Admin
```

Now Here is the question:
If a **malicious employee** be aware that there is a field named **"sth2"** for the admins, He could generate a post request **manually** and put value for **sth2** and send it to the server.

Spring will bind this value, because:

1. The field is inside Bean class
2. There is no validation for sth2 for employees

What is your solution for this?

> Suppose CSRF is disabled and we still want to use spring binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Bean {

    @NotBlank(groups = Validator.CheckForEmployee.class)
    private String sth1;


    @BlockAccess(groups = Validator.CheckForEmployee.class)
    @NotBlank(groups = Validator.CheckForAdmin.class)
    private String sth2;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Validator {
    public interface CheckForEmployee{}
    public interface CheckForAdmin{}
}


@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = BlockAccessImpl.class)
@Documented
public @interface BlockAccess {
    String message() default "Access is denied!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

public class BlockAccessImpl implements ConstraintValidator<BlockAccess, Object> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(BlockAccess constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Bean b = new Bean();
        b.setSth1("Hi");
        b.setSth2("Bye");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Bean>> s = validator.validate(b, Validator.CheckForEmployee.class);

        for (ConstraintViolation<Bean> f : s) {
            System.out.println(f.getPropertyPath() + " " + f.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> sth2 Access is denied!